# # splitting the string dynamically in sql server 2008

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008r2-express

I have a string like this:

```
","","","41","20120627063343-0210600-41"
```

I wrote my query like this to split the above string

```
declare @s varchar(max)
set @s = '","","","41","20120627063343-0210600-41"'
select right(replace(@s,',',''),26) as output
```

And I am getting the following output

```
output
-------
20120627063343-0210600-41"
```

I want the output like this for the above string

```
YEAR         TIME         NO        ID
----         -----       ----      ---- 
2012-06-27    06:33:43    0210600   41
```

Help me!

Thanks and regards,
Anand

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: @user1444281 - Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this will be as *fast* as the substring methods suggested by others, but it *might* be more readable, regardless it's another option.

```
DECLARE @parsedString VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @inputString VARCHAR(255)

SET @inputString = '","","","41","20120627063343-0210600-41"' 
SET @parsedString = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@inputString, '-', '.'), '",', '.'), '"', ''), '...', '')

SELECT  PARSENAME(@parsedString, 1) as [Id],
        PARSENAME(@parsedString, 2) as [No],
        CAST(LEFT(PARSENAME(@parsedString, 3), 8) AS DATE) as [Year],
        STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(PARSENAME(@parsedString, 3), 6), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':') as [Time]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [SUBSTRING](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFkQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx&ei=YH3tT5nIIqqI0QHUw6mEDg&usg=AFQjCNEDvAX_q69j_JaAjCFrW_RaA_F_Bw) function, and assuming that the string example of `20120627063343-0210600-41` will always be the same fixed length, you can extract all the parts you need.  Try this:

```
declare @s varchar(max)
declare @t varchar(max)
set @s = '","","","41","20120627063343-0210600-41"'
set @t = right(@s, 26) 

select left(@t, 4) + '-' + substring(@t, 5, 2) + '-' + substring(@t, 7, 2) AS [YEAR],
    substring(@t, 9, 2) + ':' + substring(@t, 11, 2) + ':' + substring(@t, 13, 2) AS [HOUR],
    substring(@t, 16, 7) AS [NO], 
    substring(@t, 24, 2) AS [ID]
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
declare @s varchar(max), @test varchar(26)
set @s = '","","","41","20120627063343-0210600-41"'
select @test = left(right(replace(@s,',',''),26),25)


select SUBSTRING(@test, 1, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@test, 5, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@test, 7, 2) as 'YEAR',
       SUBSTRING(@test, 9, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(@test, 11, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(@test, 13, 2) as 'TIME',
       SUBSTRING(@test, 16, 7) as 'NO',
       SUBSTRING(@test, 24, 2) as 'ID'
```